# No cronjobs are running but cron logs are generating in syslog

Tags: 14.04, server, cron

There are no cron jobs running in the server but cron logs are generating in syslog.  How to find out where the cron is running. I have checked in all the user but didn't find any cron.

Also I have checked in cron.hourly daily, weekly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you edit your question and post and example of the log(s) you're seeing? Probably is just cron daemon which gets executed periodically and does nothing, but logs its activity.

Comment: What about `/etc/cron.d`?

Comment: "cron logs are generating in syslog" why did you not include part of that logging? Generally I'd expect there to be a reference to where it came from.

Comment: These are the logs====> Sep 13 10:58:00 Virtualhost CRON[31794]: (root) CMD (home/ubuntu/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 13 10:59:00 Virtualhost CRON[31811]:(root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 13 11:00:00 Virtualhost CRON[31817]:(root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 13 11:01:00 Virtualhost CRON[31823]:(root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 13 11:02:00 Virtualhost CRON[31829]:(root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 13 11:03:00 Virtualhost CRON[32098]:(root) CMD (/home/ubuntu/script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at /var/spool/cron/crontabs

If it is not empty, then there is your culprit.

You will need root privileges to look at that directory.

The filenames will be of the owners usernames.